# Create Asp.net Reset Button

Tags: asp.net

Is there any ways to create reset button to clear all text in text fields in asp form? When user hits the reset button, all text entered by them will clear and they are enable to enter back text in the area.

Comment: it will not work with ASP.Net Textboxes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this create a button with reset and in click event write ClearInputs(Page.Controls); and  event will call this method.

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
}
void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
{
 foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
 {
 if (ctrl is TextBox)
  ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
 }
```

}

Comment: The problem with that is in Ajax calls. It should reset controls in the form the request came from

Answer (score 3):

As per my knowledge there is no such reset functionality provided by Asp.Net.
We can achieve the reset like this

```
btnReset.Attributes.Add("onClick", "document.forms[0].reset();return false;");
```

Or 
Like this

```
<input type='button' id='resetButton' value='Reset' onclick='theForm.reset();return false;'/>
```

Or `OnClientclick` of asp.net button use this `theForm.reset();return false;`

Answer (score 2):

In the button click method, set all textbox.text.length values to 0.  either do it one by one, which is the simple way, or do it by getting all controls of type textbox on the page, which is tad bit more sophisticated, but could be much less typing, depending on the number of textboxes.  Definitely more maintainable.

```
private void ChangeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
   {
     if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
     {
       foreach(Control c2 in c.Controls)
       {
          if (c2.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
          {
             myspan.InnerHtml = ((TextBox)c2).Text;
             ((TextBox)c2).Text = "";  //or  ((TextBox)c2).Text.Length = 0;
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20zys56y(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: If you prefer using Intellisense to typing out control class strings, you can use `typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox).ToString()` instead of `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Click` event to the `Button` control and use the following codes below:

```
foreach (Control control in Page.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
        txt.Text = "";
    }
}
```

This will save you some time to clear all the textboxes inside the web form.

Comment: What will happen when we have textboxes inside Panel etc. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery the easiest way to find any type of control and will not have post back event.

```
$('input[type=text], textarea')
```

Use foreach loop for clearing value.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
btnReset.Attributes.Add("onClick", "document.forms[0].reset();return false;");
```

will not work in clearing pages that are posted back, i.e. If a text box had a value "Silly me" and has been posted back, this code will reset to the post back value which is "Silly me".

The workaround is to repost the page with cleared values - try the following code (it worked for me)

```
OnClientClick="document.location.href=document.location.href;"
```

will reload the page with cleared values...

Comment: what is return false for ? at the end of script ?

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple type of inputs in my page (TextBox, DropDownList and CheckBox), so here is how I reset them all

1. Put an `<asp:Panel>` that wraps my inputs
2. Run `BtnClear_Click` on Clear button click
3. Loop each inputs and reset text/selection/checked value by types

The codes

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelReport" runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:TextBox ID="fldSpeedoMula" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlateNo" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCard" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCash" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" CssClass="button" OnClick="BtnClear_Click"/>  
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void BtnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear all inputs
    foreach (DropDownList ddl in PanelReport.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
    {
        ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    foreach (TextBox fld in PanelReport.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        fld.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    foreach (CheckBox cb in PanelReport.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        cb.Checked = false;
    }
}
```